# How to open only one div inside map function in react show it cannot open other div element

Tags: reactjs

this is my code part where i have used state and also setstate functin so I can toggle state but it is in map function so it is also opening other div i just wanted to know is it possible to open only one div using toggle function

```
this.state = {
        show: false            
    }

commentInputHandler = () => {
    console.log("working")
    this.setState({
        show: !this.state.show
    })
}

            <div className="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 pb-5">
                {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                    <div key={post._id} className="card mt-4">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <h4 className="card-title w-75">{post.title}</h4>
                                <div className="w-25 text-right">
                                    <span onClick={() => this.deletePost(post._id)} className="badge badge-danger cp">Delete</span>
                                    <span className="badge badge-primary cp ml-3">
                                        <Link className="text-white" to={`/postupdate/${post._id}`}>Update</Link>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p className="card-text">
                                {post.body}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer">
                            <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <span onClick={this.commentInputHandler} className="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-3 cp">Comment</span>
                                <span onClick={this.handleClickOpen} className="badge badge-pill badge-info cp">View comment</span>
                            </div>
                            {this.state.show ?
                                <div>
                                    <form className="mt-3">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Add comment"
                                        />
                                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2">Comment</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div> : null
                            }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now `show` state holds for only one boolean, you might change it to an object  that will hold each post `show` condition with `_id` as key (of course you can add it direct into `posts` state, just you didn't attach it to your code...)

---

```
this.state = {
     //inital as empty object
    show: {}
}

componentDidMount() {
   // I update state through didMount, though it is not the only truth and depends on rest code either logic
  let show = {}
  this.state.posts.map(post => show[post._id] = false)
  this.setState({show})
}
```

---

Now you can change `commentInputHandler` into something dynamic

---

```
  <span onClick={()=>this.commentInputHandler(post._id)} className="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-3 cp">Comment</span>


  commentInputHandler = id => {
     const { show } = this.state
     this.setState({
       show: {...show, [id]: !show.id}
   })
 }
```

---

and adapt your checker

---

```
  {this.state.show[post._id] ? ...
```

Comment: It helped me really but I can't use it as a toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have a single `state.show` that is shared by all the elements generated by map. You could make `state.show` an array but there is a much better way to handle this.

You should create a separate component where you will put all the code inside your map function. Put `state.show` and `commentInputHandler` inside that new child component. Then each child component will be able to show/hide itself independently of the other ones

**Parent**

```
{this.state.posts.map(post => <PostComponent key={post.id} post={post}/>)}
```

**PostComponent**

```
this.state = { show: false }

commentInputHandler = () => {
...

render()
    return (
        <div className="card mt-4">
        ...
```